# Locked console.writeline call works non-correctly

Tags: c#, multithreading, io, thread-safety, console.writeline

Trying to call Console.WriteLine from locked section, but seems it does not work correcly - console is not locked. Below is the code for simple app - two threads populate a list in parallel, and for debug purposes I'm printing the information about thread working and newly added element.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class ThreadSafe
{
    static object SyncRoot = new object();

    static int threadsCount = 0;
    static List<string> list = new List<string>();

    static void Main()
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(AddItems);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(AddItems);
        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();

        t1.Join();
        t2.Join();

        PrintItems();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void PrintItems()
    {
        string[] items;

        Console.WriteLine("Converting list to array...");
        items = list.ToArray();

        Console.WriteLine("Printing array...");
        foreach (string s in items)
            Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    static void AddItems()
    {
        int threadNo = threadsCount;
        threadsCount++;


        {
            Console.WriteLine("Populating list from {0} item in thread N {1}...", list.Count, threadNo);
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                lock (SyncRoot)
                {
                    Console.Write("Population. Thread N {0} is running. ", threadNo);
                    Console.WriteLine("Element N {0} has been added successfully.", list.Count);
                    list.Add("Item " + list.Count);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result:

```
Populating list from 0 item in thread N 1...
Population. Thread N 1 is running. Element N 0 has been added successfully.
Population. Thread N 1 is running. Element N 1 has been added successfully.
Population. Thread N 1 is running. Element N 2 has been added successfully.
Population. Thread N 1 is running. Element N 3 has been added successfully.
Population. Thread N 1 is running. Element N 4 has been added successfully.
Population. Thread N 1 is running. Element N 5 has been added successfully.
Population. Thread N 1 is running. Element N 6 has been added successfully.
Population. Thread N 1 is running. Element N 7 has been added successfully.
Population. Thread N 1 is running. Element N 8 has been added successfully.
Population. Thread N 1 is running. Element N 9 has been added successfully.
Population. Thread N 1 is running. Element N 10 has been added successfully.
Population. Thread N 1 is running. Element N 11 has been added successfully.
Population. Thread N 1 is running. Element N 12 has been added successfully.
Population. Thread N 1 is running. Element N 13 has been added successfully.
Population. Thread N 1 is running. Element N 14 has been added successfully.
Population. Thread N 1 is running. Element N 15 has been added successfully.
Population. Thread N 1 is running. Populating list from 0 item in thread N 0...
Element N 16 has been added successfully.
Population. Thread N 0 is running. Element N 17 has been added successfully.
Population. Thread N 0 is running. Element N 18 has been added successfully.
Population. Thread N 0 is running. Element N 19 has been added successfully.
```

Between steps 15 and 16 somehow the new first starts running and outputs its stuff between Console.Write and Console.WriteLine calls in the locked section... Is Console.WriteLine non thread-safe indeed? Or I'm doing something incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: The output from `thread N 0` is not in the `lock()` block. There's no reason why that shouldn't be able to be executed

Comment: The trouble with protecting a shared resource with a lock is that you have to lock *all* of the accesses.  Skip one and it no longer works correctly.

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 `AddItems` threads each making an unlocked output (the first in the function).  This interleaving is expected behaviour.  You need:

```
  lock (SyncRoot)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Populating list from {0} item in thread N {1}...", list.Count, threadNo); 
  }
```

Comment: @Default - not necessarily, because locking and unlocking on each loop might be more performant or what is needed. Separate fine-grain locks instead of one coarse-grain one is a design choice outside the scope of the original query.

Comment: @Default - np. Typically I'd avoid locking across I/O at all, and if needed (as it is here), avoid holding across multiple I/Os as this might starve competing threads.

Comment: @Steve Townsend - yes, they both do the unlocked output. My understanding of the "lock" keyword is that when I out a piece of code  into the "lock" boundaries, no other processes/threads can interrupt execution of the "locked" code. Is this correct? If so, I'm wondering why output from other thread (Thread N0) appear between two locked outputs in thread N1.

Comment: Your understanding is not correct (but don't worry, it's a common error initially). What `lock` actually does is provide exclusive access **versus all threads using the same lock**. Any thread not using a lock, or locking something else, can continue to run in parallel. As @Hans noted, you cannot lock just some of the usage of Console, you have to lock it all if multiple threads are in play concurrently.

Comment: + locking each iteration may not make any sense in real life, but I'm just playing around with multithreading and per-iteration lock guarantee switching between threads on the list population. With the whole cycle locked I'd just get sequential threads running, no "parallelism" of the list population.

Comment: I like your fine-grained lock here.  Locking outside a loop with I/O inside smells wrong to me, independent of your purpose with thsi code.

Comment: @Steve Townsend - ah, seems I got it. When I do writing to console from multiple threads, I have to lock all of them. Thanks, now it's clear!

Answer (score 2):

The line:

`Console.WriteLine("Populating list from {0} item in thread N {1}...", list.Count, threadNo);`

appears outside the synchronised block.

Answer (score 1):

Some of your code is outside the locked part. First thing:

```
int threadNo = threadsCount;
        threadsCount++;
```

is not thread safe. Imagine a thread starting and being interrupted by second thread before it can increment the thread count. Both thread will then have `threadNo = 0`

But that doesn't seems to be an issue here, although can cause problems if you are using it do some computations.

As pointed out by others: you need to lock  `Console.WriteLine("Populating list from {0} item in thread N {1}...", list.Count, threadNo);` also, so when the next thread starts, it waits to write on the Console while the other thread is writing too.

Comment: Yep, agree that the piece with threadNo and threadsCount++ should be put into locked part. I guess because of this I got "Populating list from 0 item" instead of "16 item" at the original code. Done the lock of threadsCount++ as you advised + moved the quoted Console.WriteLine + added sleep after t1.Start() and t2.Start() calls + added short sleep (50 milliseconds) into the list popilation cycle (for i) - the result is much more evident and illustrative.

Comment: I think you don't need sleep with locking. It should work without sleeps

Answer (score 0):

Console.WriteLine("Populating list from {0} item in thread N {1}...", list.Count, threadNo); is not inside the locked region so can be printed at any time as you saw.